# Can someone help me understand != in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm working on learning Ruby on codecademy. I've gotten to comparators and am sure I'm not understanding !=.
The directions say, exactly "You can also check to see if two values are not equal using the != comparator." 
What's the need to check whether something is specifically NOT equal to something else? Does this only apply to numbers? Would anyone be willing to give me 2-3 examples?

Comment: `variable != null` for null checks?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can improve your question. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) including the link "How to ask questions the smart way."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some examples of `!=`

```
"a string" != "another string"
[1,2,3] != [3,2,1]
{ key: "value" } != { key: "another value" }
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: But what common applications?

Comment: Does != specifically only check for non-equality? Does it only produce true/false?

Comment: Checking whether two objects (or primitives in other languages) is a common programming task in almost every programming language. Maybe you are writing a Quiz application and you are checking if the user's entered value is the right answer so you use `!=` to display some info. `correct_answer !=  users_answer`

Comment: `!=` returns true or false. `true` if the values are not equal to each other and `false` if the values are equal to each other. It is the same as `!(a == b)`

Comment: Thank you so much, that cleared everything up!

Answer (score 2):

1. Can be used when validating passwords:

> ```
> if password_entered_on_form != password_stored_in_server
>    stop_them_from_logging_in
> end
> ```

2. General examples:

> ```
>     if country_of_origin != USA
>        check_work_permit_restrictions
>     else
>        no_working_restrictions
>     end
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You could for example, check if an object is nil.

```
my_car = Car.new
if my_car != nil
  #do something
end
```